# Does "entity" refer to an object or a set of objects?

Tags: database, entity, data-modeling

Take **person** for example
Does the Person entity refer to Jon Doe as a single person or the people as a whole ?
For example in a table in a database, is there a **Table** which holds a set of entities or an **Entity** which holds some records ?
Apart from database, how about data modelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Entity Relationship model, **entity** refers to a thing which 
can be distinctly identified. A specific person, company, or event is an example of an entity. A population of entities of the same type is called an **entity set**. When an entity set is identified and described via attributes, we get an **entity relation**, which can be represented as a table in a database.

Note that tables are also used to represent relationship relations, so it's not correct to equate tables with entity sets or relations. It's also not correct to equate a row with a single entity - rather, a row represents a fact about one or more entities.